# Can Joomla send the user an email after admin approves them?

Tags: joomla, user-management, joomla3.9

Problem is:

1. User registers at the side and gets a registration email with a
   confirmation link which can be used. and
2. Admin gets an email notification of a newly registered user
3. Admin activates & enables the user
4. No notification email to the user is sent about his accounts activation

No hints in the logs. Mailserver is working as described. Tests with System emails active for users show no difference in the behavior. Also added true to `$return = JFactory::getMailer()->sendMail($data['mailfrom'], $data['fromname'], $data['email'], $emailSubject, $emailBody, true);` in registeration.php

Does this feature actually work? Any help in solving this would be much-appreatiated.

Using Joomla 3.9.15 and no external plugins for user-management.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla distinguishes between user activation by link through email or via administration backend. In order to send an email to the user after the activation of the user account one needs to use the link from the email. Activation from the administration backend will not send an email to the user who's account was activated.